# Access is asking me for Parameter Values in query that worked last week

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have 2 combo boxes on a form that were working before this week. I do not know why, but all of a sudden they are asking me for Parameter values, when before it would filter based off the selections of other combo boxes. I will lay out the structure and my methodology. First the structure -

The first 2 boxes are **Customer Name** and **Ship To Location**. When I enter in a customer from the list, it is supposed to then filter Ship to Location based off of that input Customer's Name. I have this SQL in the Row Source for **Ship To Location:**

```
SELECT Tbl_CustomerShipToLocation.Ship_To_Location, Tbl_MasterCustomerList.Customer_Name
FROM Tbl_MasterCustomerList INNER JOIN Tbl_CustomerShipToLocation ON Tbl_MasterCustomerList.Customer_ID = Tbl_CustomerShipToLocation.Customer_ID
WHERE (((Tbl_MasterCustomerList.Customer_Name)=[Forms]![Frm_SalesOrdersEntry]![Customer_Name]));
```

The second set of boxes are **Part Number** and **Unit of Measure**. When I enter in a part number from the list, it is supposed to filter the Unit of Measure based off of that input Part Number. I have this SQL in the Row Source for **Unit of Measure:**

```
SELECT Tbl_JobTicketUoM.Access_ID, Tbl_JobTicketUoM.Unit_of_Measure
FROM Tbl_JobTicketUoM
WHERE (((Tbl_JobTicketUoM.Access_ID)=[Forms]![Frm_SalesOrdersEntry]![Part_Number]));
```

My VBA code for both of them look like this:

```
Private Sub Customer_Name_AfterUpdate()

Me.Ship_To_Location.Requery

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Part_Number_AfterUpdate()

Me.Unit_Of_Measure.Requery

End Sub
```

They were working last week, and then I logged in this morning and went to add a Sales Order and encountered this error before I even could.
[image: This Error]

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: That error message has nothing to do with missing query parameters.  I think you should make sure to include `Option Explicit` in your form module's Declarations section and then run Debug->Compile from the VBE main menu.  If Access complains about a compile error, what else does it say and what in your code is highlighted?

Comment: @HansUp I have option explicit, and when I compile everything it comes out fine; no errors. I had thought they were related as the only AfterUpdate events I have in this form are those two. The only other subs in this form are: 2 for button clicks on that form, and then one private sub that fires on unload to reset default values of other controls. I can post all of that, but I don't think I am having any issues with those subs as the buttons are still working 100% as intended.

Comment: In that case, there may be name confusion going on.  Try a quick test.  Make a copy of your form and rename the combo boxes to `cboShipToLocation` and `cboUnitOfMeasure` then revise the `AfterUpdate()` procedures to requery those names.   Does the error go away?

Comment: @HansUp I cannot believe it was that easy. I suppose it is because I reference default values in the unload event I talked about earlier, and that is written using the Field Names. My guess would be naming their form controls the exact same thing really messed Access on which one I was talking about. Thank you for your patience, this has been a couple hour headache at this point, and I'd rather feel like a bit of an idiot for not covering my bases than the level of frustration I had this morning lol.

Edit: If you would like answer credit then post your comment as an answer and I will mark.

Comment: My advice is to prefix data control names (with cbo, txt, lst etc.) to distinguish them from the names of fields in the form's record source.  And IMO control names should never include spaces.

Comment: @HansUp It's near impossible to tell when I just post VBA, but those are actually all underscores in control and form names. I struggled initially with reading some names in CamelCase as I have a slight bit of dyslexia, so adding underscores helped it stay easily readable for me as well as not having the issues that come with spaces when referencing things with straight SQL or in VBA (except here funnily enough lol).